# Transaction in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions, rollback, mysql-5.5

I am working on a c# application with Mysql database(version 5.5).
I am facing an issue where I need to catch an exception occurred in Mysql.
It doesn't matter whether it is caught in Mysql or in dotNet. The problem is that I want to rollback all my previous work when an exception/error is occurred; be it of MySqlException or custom one.
And yes, I tried using `TransactionScope` and `MySqlTransaction` but it didn't rollback my work.
If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, please guide me.
Thanks.

Edit:Code

```
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cnstring);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        TransactionScope ob = new TransactionScope();
        try
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("testProcedureSignal", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("pval", 1));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@intException", MySqlDbType.Int32) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@strErrorMessage", MySqlDbType.VarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            con.Close();
            ob.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        ob.Complete();
        con.Close();
```

And this is the Procdeure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testProcedureSignal`(
pval INT,
OUT intException INT,
OUT strErrorMessage VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN
ROLLBACK;
END;
SET intException = 100;
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO demo (data) values (intException);
SET intException = intException + 10;
INSERT INTO demo (data) values (intException);
DROP TABLE teeeee;-- this table does not exist
INSERT INTO demo2 (data1,data2) values ('demo2',intException + 10);
SET intException = 111;
SET intException = 2;
COMMIT;
END
```

Comment: If you're using InnoDB tables, I can't see any reason that TransactionScope would not work. If you're using MyISAM tables it will _not_ work since MyISAM has no transactions.

Comment: Please share your - relevant - code with SO. We cannot say why it did not work for you without having something to look at.

Comment: All are InnoDB tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I brought the thing to the notice of my superiors.
And well, we have now MySQL version 5.6 where there is a simple and easy way to implement `TRY-CATCH` scenario. And now, I am using the following code in all my stored procedures.

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN
ROLLBACK;
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
strErrorMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT;
SET intException = 53300;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this article (I found it via Google, nothing hidden): http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/

Scroll down to the "Transaction Support" section. You do not have the .Commit() or .Rollback() methods used in your code.

You have to use the `MySqlTransaction` class to achieve the results you are looking for. You call `.Commit()` or `.Rollback()` accordingly, see the link I posted above for all required info and snippets.

Check this link as well: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqltransaction.html. It describes the `MySqlTransaction` class with its methods and some best practices.

Comment: I have tried with `MySqlTransaction` too and also have mentioned it in my question, its just that I haven't written that code here.
Thanks for the links, let me have a look at this and see whether it works or not